# Can we direct the netsh.exe to dump its output to a xml file?

Tags: networking, operating-system, netsh, tcp

Assuming I am entering the following command in the command prompt:

```
netsh.exe interface ip show config "Local Area Connection" > c:\temp\dump.txt
```

this command dumps the output to a text file. I want the same output to be dumped in xml format. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported nativly. But you can use the PowerShell DHCP Cmdlets from Jeremy Engel:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/05b1d766-25a6-45cd-a0f1-8741ff6c04ec

This will create PowerShell object's around the netsh commands and then you can create from this objects xml files.